# How to Select From Nativescript Picker on Android

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, appium, ui-automation

We have recently upgraded our mobile Nativescript framework from version 6.something to version 7 (latest). This has changed the appearance and function of various dropdowns to instead show List Picker or Number Picker elements in our native mobile app.

I am using typescript/javascript and appium to automate my mobile tests.

Now I am not able to select an element from these types of pickers. I have tried various locators and methods that I could find online (not much info out there to be honest). I have tried to sendKeys directly to the picker element (it complains saying you can't send keys to this type of element for android), have tried tapping element with text in the picker (it skips over this and nothing happens visually), etc.

[Here is example of how one of these pickers might look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5A11.png)

Here is example of code that I have tried to use (note the ios code works but the android code is commented out because those are various things I have tried to no avail):

```
 public async selectDataFromDropdownNS7(dropdownData: string): Promise<void> {
        // iOS
        if (this.driver.isIOS) {
            wait(2000)
            const listPicker = await this.driver.findElementByClassName('UIAPickerWheel')
            await listPicker.sendKeys(`${dropdownData}`)
            await (await this.driver.findElementByText('Done')).tap()
        } else {
            // android.widget.EditText android.widget.NumberPicker android.widget.Button
            const numberPicker = await this.driver.findElementByClassName('android.widget.EditText')
            // const wd = this.driver.wd()
            // const action = new wd.TouchAction(this.driver.driver)
            // action
            //     .longPress({ x: 200, y: 1000 })
            //     .wait(5000)
            //     .moveTo({ x: 200, y: 200 })
            //     .release()
            // await action.perform()
            // await numberPicker.sendKeys(dropdownData)
            // await (await this.driver.findElementByText(`${dropdownData}`)).tap()
            // await (await this.driver.findElementByText('Done')).tap()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hve you checked this project https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium for some ideas?

Comment: I have yes, that is what we use. But they don't have any specific info like what I'm looking for, they have a few very simple examples of locating elements and such. Also this git project doesn't get a lot of activity, so it's not that great for new changes.